# Itext PDF table cell's data is not coming on second page

Tags: java, itext

I am using pdfptable to print. Cell, when table is reaching at end of page and any cell which is carrying more data and with same cell continuation is not coming next page , actually it is truncating data of cell . I am using single table in my code to print data

Does it possible to solve this issue?

Comment: Please edit your question with the code you are actually using. Also, indicate which version of iText you are using.